# Linq - highest occurring value

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql

My requirement is to fetch data using Linq, based on highest occurring value.

```
       var Output = (from s in  dt2.AsEnumerable()
                    from c in  dt1.AsEnumerable()
                    where Regex.IsMatch(s.Field<string>("CODE1"), c.Field<string>("CODE1")) &&
                          Regex.IsMatch(s.Field<string>("SAMPLE"), c.Field<string>("CODE2"))                                                           
                      select new
                     {
                         OCCURANCE = c.Field<int>("OCCURANCE"),
                         CODE1 = s.Field<string>("CODE1"),
                         SAMPLE = s.Field<string>("SAMPLE"),
                     });
```

Receiving output as bellow -

|  | OCCURANCE | CODE1 | SAMPLE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 120 | VP10 | OB-444 |
| 2 | 120 | VP10 | OC-555 |
| 3 | 120 | VP10 | OD-666 |
| 4 | 100 | VP10 | OD-666 |

From the above result set, 3rd and 4th row contains same data in CODE1 and SAMPLE column. But i need to fetch the record which has highest OCCURANCE value, hence I need to fetch row no 3 instead and exclude row no 4.

My required output is as given bellow -

| OCCURANCE | CODE1 | SAMPLE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 120 | VP10 | OB-444 |
| 120 | VP10 | OC-555 |
| 120 | VP10 | OD-666 |

Comment: Just do group by code and sample and order the groups by occurance taking the highest one. `.GroupBy(x => new { x.CODE1, x.SAMPLE}).Select(grp => grp.OrderBy(x => x.OCCURANCE).Last())`